# Converting Character to Date Class in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have an R dataset filled with character strings that look like this:

`date <- "2019-03-12T14:32:24.000-01:00"`

Is there a way to convert this date and time to a date class where both the date 2019-03-12 and the time T14:32:24.000-01:00 are displayed? I need a way to manipulate these dates later on, so I can find the time difference between two dates down to the seconds. I'm building the solution in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lubridate`'s `ymd_hms`.

```
date <- "2019-03-12T14:32:24.000-01:00"
date1 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(date)
date1
#[1] "2019-03-12 15:32:24 UTC"
```

Note that timezone has changed to UTC now and hence you see a different time.

If you only want the date you can use `as.Date` and extract the time part with `format`.

```
as.Date(date1)
#[1] "2019-03-12"

format(date1, '%T')
#[1] "15:32:24"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use [`anytime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anytime/versions/0.3.9)

```
library(anytime)
anytime(date)
#[1] "2019-03-12 14:32:24 EDT"
```

If we want only the `Date`, use `anydate`

```
anydate(date)
#[1] "2019-03-12"
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
as.POSIXct(date, format = '%FT%T')
#[1] "2019-03-12 14:32:24 EDT"
```

#### data

```
date <-  "2019-03-12T14:32:24.000-01:00"
```